# interacting from the display with a loop on doc in WORD VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Intending to develop a WORD macro I have a question of how to.
Intention is to for-loop over a collection of docs (acquired in any suitable way – not a problem).
Each document  will be opened and displayed on the screen, allowing the user to apply any (simple) editing. The for-loop should therefore be "interrupted-paused" and somehow wait till the user closes (or otherwise signals his abandoning) the currently active document.
Short of listing all doc names in the loop and, after loop end and macro end, manually opening and processing them one by one, I do not see how to do it in code.
(Note: I am not a beginner on VBA, but my experience is mainly in Access VBA, with some tens of thousands of lines of code – I am not overly familiar with the WORD object model, though. I suspect that some event processing with or without explicit event raising, might be required … or not)

Comment: You can collect all of the file paths into (eg) a collection or array, then open a modeless userform with a "Next" button, which opens each file in turn and then waits for the user to click "Next" before saving the current file and opening the next one.

Comment: Or you could create a Word AddIn (aka 'global template' in "Word-speak") which would show the first document in your list then wait for the `DocumentChange` or maybe `WindowDeactivate` event to trigger and in that event handler then check that the document has actually been closed and then show the next document and so on until all documents in the list have been shown

Comment: Thanks. Your first suggestion is roughly what I envisaged as one way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Your first suggestion is roughly what I envisaged as one way to go.
The second however is somewhat beyond my knowledge of word.  There I really need more detail, if that is not too much to ask. I am familiar with template, as basic knowledge. But that's it. Biased by my Access knowledge, I would expect that the events you mention are to be handled in a userform module? Or not...?